# Problems with attaching textures of different sizes to FBO

Tags: c, opengl, nvidia, framebuffer

Today I faced a strange problem while I was developing my OpenGL 4.5 application. I attempted to attach two textures of different sizes to one FBO as color attachments in order to create a bloom shader. As far as I know, in modern OpenGL versions this should be possible.

This is the code I'm using:

```
//Create textures
GLuint tex[2];
glCreateTextures( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, tex );
glTextureStorage2D( tex[0], 1, GL_RGB8, 2048, 2048 );
glTextureStorage2D( tex[1], 1, GL_RGB8, 1024, 1024 );

//Create FBO
GLuint fbo;
glCreateFramebuffers( 1, &fbo );
glNamedFramebufferTexture( fbo, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex[0], 0 );
glNamedFramebufferTexture( fbo, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, tex[1], 0 );

//Check completeness
GLenum comp = glCheckNamedFramebufferStatus( fbo, GL_FRAMEBUFFER );
```

I'd expect `comp` to be `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`, however, in my case `glCheckNamedFramebufferStatus` returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS_EXT`.

I'm afraid it might be some driver bug, based on these two threads, since apparently `INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS` has been removed from newer OpenGL versions:

- http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=4207.0
- [devtalk.nvidia.com topic](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1030494/bug-amp-amp-spec-violation-checknamedframebufferstatus-returns-gl_framebuffer_incomplete_dimensions_ext-under-gl-4-5-core/)

Here's the full code to illustrate the issue - https://pastebin.com/c9Hqzzky.
My output is:

```
0x8cd9
0x8cd9 - GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS_EXT
fbotest: fbotest.c:41: main: Assertion `comp != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS_EXT' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have Nvidia GTX 1060 graphics card, Ubuntu 18.04LTS and Nvidia driver version 390.67.

Has anyone seen similar behavior before? If so, what are possible workarounds?
Thank you for help in advance

Comment: Hi.Have you solved this one? I am experiencing exactly the same status in a similar use case.

Comment: @MichaelIV Unfortunately, I still haven't solved this issue. Just to make sure nothing has changed, I tried running the example code posted here. Results are identical.

Comment: I can tell you why I got that thing in my case. I have also stencil attachment which has different size (bigger) than the color attachment.If I remove that stencil buffer,then the problem solved.That's strange thing,because I thought that OpenGL allows also non color attachment to be of varying sizes.But it looks like it doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelIV In my case, I wanted to have a FBO with multiple color attachments to implement deferred rendering and bloom effect based on two-pass Gaussian filter. Thus, I needed an additional attachment with its size transposed - and that's when I faced the problem. If I remove the additional attachment or change its dimensions to match other ones, it works fine. Apparently, to reproduce this issue, there's no need for non-color attachments. It's just weird... I will try running this code on PC with different GPU and drivers tomorrow, and let you know the results.

Comment: @MichaelIV I asked my friend to run this code and the results are identical. He has the same driver version and Nvidia GT 440 graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an Nvidia bug with ARB DSA (which I've filed last Februrary), if you use non-Named versions it will not give a validation error.

Comment: I am getting this one with DSA API. I am on driver  V 411.81

Comment: its a confirmed driver bug